# Twitter Bootstrap: Switch classes depending on the viewport size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Let's say I have the following markup:

```
<div class="span6"></div>
<div class="span6"></div>
```

Now let's say that if the viewport is smaller than 600px, I want to make the DIVs span acrros the whole container, like so:

```
<div class="span12"></div>
<div class="span12"></div>
```

My solution is the following:

```
<div class="do-not-display-below-600px">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>

<div class="do-not-display-above-600px">
    <div class="span12"></div>
    <div class="span12"></div>
</div>
```

And simply hide or show the `do-not-display...` classes using media queries.

This is a horrible solution because it violates the "Don't repeat yourself" rule. Assuming that I have 5 breakpoints, I would have to create 5 different containers for each breakpoint. That's ugly.

So I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution?

PS: I realize I could use Bootstrap's LESS mixins or bootstrap-sass to `@include` the mixins into each class where I need them, but is there another solution?

Comment: Why not just use media queries, and override the styles defined by Bootstrap yourself?

Comment: Yep, using media queries to patch yout Bootstrap. Sometimes you need do more than just use an predefined solution.

Comment: Hm. I don't really like this solution, because if a new version of Bootstrap came along, I couldn't just update Bootstrap's `.css` files...

Comment: Is Twitter designing your site or are you?  This example right here is why the whole grid `span6`/`span12` naming convention is a bad idea and makes no sense.